# Excel counta function

Tags: excel, function, ms-office

Hi I have a column of numbers where some begin with "083", "082" or "086" etc...(example of how the number is formatted: 083-5694878). What I would like to know is: Is there a function that will allow me to count the number of cells that begin with either 083 or 082? Bear in mind that I have a list of about 70 000 people.

Answer (score 4):

If the data is formatted as text (which it must be if "-" is part of the cell contents) then you can use COUNTIF with a "wildcard", e.g. with data in column A this formula will count those that begin with "083"

`=COUNTIF(A:A,"083*")`

or if you have 083 in a cell, e.g. D2 use this formula

`=COUNTIF(A:A,D2&"*")`

Comment: As an add on to this, if you need the count of both "083" and "082", you can just sum them `COUNTIF(A:A,"083*") + COUNTIF(A:A,"082*")`

Comment: If you want to combine the counts you can also do that like this: `=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,{"082*","083*"}))`